# Присвоить класс самому верхнему родителю

Tags: javascript

Народ, помогите разобраться пожалуйста. В общем у меня есть не очень адекватная, древняя структура html в виде таблицы. К моему глубочайшему сожалению, отойти от этого абсурда мне не разрешают.

В примере привожу дэмо кусок этой таблицы.

Мне необходимо сделать так, чтоб в каждой такой конструкции на странице, брался класс картинки ( в моем случае это `class="status_off"`) и копировался в самое верхнее `tr` (в примере я закомментировал основные элементы, с которыми нужно пошаманить).

Т.е. в конечном итоге, при загрузке страницы каждая вот такая картинка должна отдать свой класс самому верхнему родителю данной конструкции `=> tr`.

Т.е. сделать 7 шагов вверх и присвоить класс картинки. Помогите пожалуйста, а то я что-то вообще не соображу. На сколько я понимаю, тут нужно использовать `.parentNode` 7 раз. Не могу правильно воспользоваться `getElementsByClassName`

Заранее спасибо!

P.S. Таких конструкций на странице всегда разное кол-во. Вся эта конструкция это одна строчка огромной таблицы.

Пример код:

```
<tr> <!-- вот тут должен появиться класс -->
<td>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    <a class="links_ngt">информация </a>
                </td>

                <td align="right">
                    <font color="red">
                        <b class="kat_min">Группа "б"</b>
                    </font>
                </td>

                <td align="right">
                    <span id="disable_link_108663">
                        <img id="off_stat" class="status_off" title="оповещение" src="https://home.yastatic.net/morda-logo/i/afisha_color_62.png"><!-- вот от сюда должен скопироваться класс -->
                    </span>
                </td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
```

```
var off = Document.getElementsByClassName('status_off');
var parent = off.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
parent.classList.add('status_off');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/malefikus13/wtjty2jL/6/

Буду безумно Вам благодарен за помощь!

Comment: А JQuery можно юзать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример, работает даже если количество шагов к самому верхнему `tr` изменится.

```js
var off = document.getElementsByClassName('status_off'),
  length = off.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  var node = off[i];
  var parent = node.parentNode,
    tr;
  while (parent) {
    if (parent.tagName === 'TR') {
      tr = parent;
    }
    parent = parent.parentNode;
  }
  if (tr) {
    tr.classList.add('status_off');
  }
}
```

```css
.status_off {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <!-- вот тут должен появиться класс -->
    <td>
      <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td align="left"> <a class="links_ngt">информация </a>

            </td>
            <td align="right"> <font color="red">
                            <b class="kat_min">Группа "б"</b>
                        </font>

            </td>
            <td align="right"> <span id="disable_link_108663">
                            <img id="off_stat" class="status_off" title="оповещение" src="https://home.yastatic.net/morda-logo/i/afisha_color_62.png"><!-- вот от сюда должен скопироваться класс -->
                        </span>

            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for(var i=0, last, parent; i < images.length;i++) {
    last = undefined;
    parent = images[i].parentNode;

    while(parent = parent.parentNode) {
        if(parent.tagName && parent.tagName.toLowerCase() == "tr") {
            last = parent;
        }
    }

    if(last != undefined) {
        last.classList.add(images[i].className);
    }
}
```

Как-то так наверное. Сначала получаем все изображения. Затем в цикле ищем всех родителей и сравниваем по тегу. Берем последний TR тег и добавляем ему класс изображения.

jQuery:

```
$('tr img').each(function() {
    $(this).parents("tr").last().addClass($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

Comment: спасибо большое! Все варианты работают!